# Deleting sections from a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm writing an iOS app and I have a UITableView that starts out with 2 sections.  What I want is that if someone deletes all of the rows from the first section then the entire section will disappear.  My question is, when I delete section 0, does the remaining section now become section 0? Or is it still considered section 1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When I delete section 0, does the remaining section now become section 0?

Yes, of course. You need to update your data model properly before committing the deletion, or UITableView will most likely throw some heavy NSExceptions against you (personal experience).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible. You just need to update the DataSource. After updating you just need to relaod the tableView. It will get reflected.